# How to simply update entity in entity framework?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm writing a custom .NET MembershipProvider (not the built in one) and trying to update using Entity Framework. But of course i have no access to (Try)UpdateModel. How can i update it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have updated your Q to include the fact you have a custom Membership provider. Because not knowing that, my answer was basically a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this kind of thing with the ASP.NET Membership Provider, that is, write custom updates to the tables.

If it were that easy, less people would have issues/problems with it. =)

Don't even bother adding the ASP.NET Membership SQL Tables onto your EDMX - you won't know the relationships or how the tables really work together. Forget about trying to represent it as a "Model".

My advice is don't try and bind to the MembershipProvider as a Model (i.e dont create a strongly typed view), just call the Membership methods directly from your controller.

This is where we start to miss the 'drag and drop' of Web Forms, can't drop on a ChangePassword control. =)

Your best bet would be to create a regular view (not strongly typed), then have regular buttons that post to your controller methods.

Don't try and pass through the object as a model, get the fields in the Request.Form collection.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePassword()
{
   string userName = Request.Form["userName"];
   string passWord = Request.Form["passWord"];
   MembershipProvider.ChangePassword(userName, password);       
   return View("ChangePasswordSuccess");
}
```

The above code would be (roughly) the equivalent of passing through a strongly typed User object, changing the password and calling UpdateModel.

Of course, you **could** implement your own membership provider, but i dont believe implementing a custom provider just to make your code "easier" should be the driver, because unless coded properly (which is not easy to do), you compromise a lot of the built-in security features and wealth of account management options of the ASP.NET Membership provider that we take for granted.

Comment: +1. [Don't map the membership tables](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/03/05/38558/)

Answer (score 0):

To do this with the default provider is a little complicated, however what would be much easier would be to create your own CustomMembershipProvider as outlined here:

[Implementing A Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)

As you can do this to your OWN account model, you can code the repository/DAL code however you choose, and use standard EF practices and conventions, allowing you to perform simple and strongly mapped operations such as UpdateModel.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is writing my own Membership Provider, but I dunno how to update my EF entity from there.

Comment: Ah, what you need Sir. is a DAL layer, or a Repository, I strongly reccomend using this example from Dane Morgridge, he provides a T4 template, simply place this in the same folder as your EDMX model, and run, and it will generate a data repository for your model (or at least the bones of one that you can then customise).

http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/Default.aspx

Comment: @Agares, writing your own Membership provider has nothing to do with updating the EF entity - this is a standard EF technique, just have a look around and you'll find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620350/can-i-use-entity-framework-with-asp-net-membership).

Here is a CodeProject sample app that could get you started that uses EF and Microsoft's MembershipProvider.  There is a class they built that inherits from MembershipProvider.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/EFMembershipProvider.aspx