# How to make sql membership provider and entity framework work using my database?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, connection-string

I have .NET MVC 3 project where I use sql membership provider and entity framework.

I've created new database on my SQL server and created all objects for membership provider using `aspnet_regsql.exe`, I've changed my connection string and it works fine.

Now I want to use entity framework for db interaction. I'm using Code-First so I created simple entity class and I can save data to db and retreive it.

The problem is that the place where entity framework keeps it's data is a mistery. I can not find any database in my project and there are no new tables in my SQL database.

If I add second connection string to web.config (the first one is for membership provider) my entity framework stops working (I assume it should create new tables in my DB) but it does not do it.

My entity class looks like:

```
public class MyEntities : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Business> Businesses { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm getting an exception `Invalid object name 'dbo.Businesses'`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

my connection strings look like this:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
   connectionString="Data Source=.;  
                     Initial Catalog=MyDbName;  
                     Persist Security Info=True;  
                     User ID=sa;  
                     Password=mypassword"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
<add name="MyEntities"
     connectionString="data source=.;
                      Initial Catalog=MyDbName;
                      Persist Security Info=True;
                      User ID=sa;
                      Password=mypassword"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
 />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/EFMembershipProvider.aspx this is good example which implements custome membership provider with entity framework. And read this first
[Can I use Entity Framework with ASP.NET Membership?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620350/can-i-use-entity-framework-with-asp-net-membership)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. To say the truth I did not want to customize the membership provider, I only want to make it work on it's own and persist my data using entity framework. I can't make entity framework to se my database:(

Comment: Then use database first and create your edmx file using the membership database. Then you will have access to DB though EF and Membership provider.

Comment: Ok, now I use model first approach, I generated simple model and see the table is created in my DB, it sounds silly but now I can not find how to use my model, how can I add ne entry there?

Comment: just rihg click on edmx and add new entity. here is a good tutorial.http://blog.garypretty.co.uk/index.php/2009/05/20/tutorial-entity-framework-v20-model-first-using-visual-studio-2010-and-net-40/

Answer (score 2):

I've just spent 2 hours trying to solve this problem, and i finally got it)

Just let the EF create your database first (using CodeFirst method), and then use aspnet_regsql.exe to add membership tables to the database.

It doesn't work the other way around :(

I have added EF DbContext to the home page controller, so that EF would create the database at the first launch of the site.

```
namespace Rem.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        DataEntities db = new DataEntities(); <--------------

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Домашняя страница";

            City c = db.Cities.Find(5); <--------------------

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Описание сайта";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Контактные данные";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

After that i just ran the aspnet utility.

To avoid duplication of connection strings i pass connectionString name to DbContext constructor in my DataContext derived class constructor:

```
namespace Rem.Models
{
    public class DataEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
        public DataEntities():base(@"dbcs") { ; } <----------
    }
}
```