# Advanced Permission Management - role and entity dependant

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

This is a fairly advanced design question for which I cannot seem to find a simple answer.

It is similar to this question:
[Manage entity access and permissions with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033458/manage-entity-access-and-permissions-with-entity-framework)

A slim version of the system:

1. We have 6 different kinds of users in 3 categories.

   - Supplier: users
   - Supplier: Admin users
   - InternalFactory: users
   - InternalFactory: Admin users
   - Admin: Maintenance users
   - Admin: Super users
     Admin, Supplier and InternalFactory groups are all mutually exclusive.
2. We have a page which allows one to edit an Entity. Lets use a "Shipment" as an example. Shipments are created only by suppliers or admins. Shipments can only be edited if....

   - It is the last shipment edited (Applies to all roles, except Admin roles.)
   - It is owned by the same supplier company as the user (Applies to Supplier roles)
   - It is owned by a supplier company related to the users InternalFactory. (Applies to only InternalFactory roles)

So the problem is, the editing permission depends on properties of the object, and also the users role. So my code ends up being very messy and I am often making mistakes - this is an excerpt of some different code, so you get the idea. I have not implemented what I said above.

Permissions are granted to certain roles, which are used probably in the wrong way, and then other things determined from the Entity properties to see if it is "our" shipment etc

```
 public bool CheckCanEdit(EntityDto input)
        {

            if (
                IsGranted(PermissionNames.EditAnyShipments)
                ||
                (IsGranted(PermissionNames.EditShipments) && _shipmentsRepo.GetAllForEdit().Where(s =>
                    s.Id == input.Id && s.SupplierId == AbpSession.TenantId).Count() > 0
                    )
                ||
                (IsGranted(PermissionNames.EditClientShipments) && _shipmentsRepo.GetAllForEdit().Where(s =>
                    s.Id == input.Id && s.FactoryId == AbpSession.TenantId).Count() > 0
                )
             )
            {
                return true;
            }


            return false;

        }
```

This is actually a simpler case, but you can see where it's going.

What I want is to have a simple method I can call and it will tell me if the user can edit the entity. I have achieved the "can-call-easily" functionality by putting this method inside the service "Shipments" along with all the other "Update" etc functions. This is great, as I can also call this from the Api and the UI can get the same logic.

BUT, I feel this is 1) Heavy, and 2) messy.
It is heavy because for example if I want to load a list of 100 shipments, and show an "Edit" button, they will all need to be called for individually before the UI knows to show the button or not.
It is messy because the code inside the "CheckCanEdit" function is not nice and logical. I am hoping for something better in terms of design; A tutorial or lecture or explanation of how to deal with this in a "best practice" kind of way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to this problem was using the [Specification Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern), an implementation [shown here in ASP ABP](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Specifications)

A specification can be like: `EditableShipments`
And within this specification, an expression is returned depending on which permission a user has.

```
public class EditableShipmentSpecification : Specification<Shipment>, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IPermissionChecker _permiss;
    public EditableShipmentSpecification(IPermissionChecker permis)
    {
        _permiss = permis;
    }

    public override Expression<Func<Shipment, bool>> ToExpression()
    {
        //if this is true, we can edit regardless
        bool skipermission = _permiss.IsGranted(PermissionNames.AllowShipmentEditEvenIfInvoiced);

        //Admins
        if (_permiss.IsGranted(PermissionNames.FullEdit_Any_Shipment))
            return (shipment) => (!shipment.IsDeleted);


        //FactoryAdmins
        // Only last is fully editable
        if (_permiss.IsGranted(PermissionNames.CanEditLastShipment))
            return (shipment) => !shipment.IsDeleted &&
                shipment.Order.IsDeleted == false &&
                shipment.Order.Shipment.Where(s => s.IsDeleted == false).Max(o => o.BatchNum) == shipment.BatchNum
                && (shipment.InvoiceId == null || skipermission)
                ;

        //default
        return (shipment) => (false);
    }
}
```

This was my solution in the end which works very well as we can use the `ToExpression` function of `Specifications` to use it as a query, or the `IsSatisfiedBy` function to make quick comparisons for enabling `Edit` buttons ect on the view.